# Sharing a text to Evernote in iphone sdks

Tags: iphone

How to share a Note or a text to evernote in iphone sdk?i downloaded the API along with the sample project from the EverNote website,but the sample application is not working,it crashes.
after some googling i get this [link](http://digitalpericope.net/?p=27),but i didnt know how to implement this.but i just want to know how to share a text from a application to evernote.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u completed this job?...Please guide me the links  @stackiphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you means to send a text you get from a application as a new note to evernote? You can just use createNote:: function in evernote SDK on iOS. In evernote SDK, there have some sample code   which is written by evernote employee to teach you how to use SDK.

Comment: http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/ this is evernote sdk. you can find the sample code in /cocoa, which have finished login and createNote function in this sample project. I think this is enough for you to finish your job.

Comment: ,but i think i download this sample application,but there is no login form there....all are stattilayy implemented ....

Comment: download the last version evernote sdk 1.21, and you can find code in \evernote-api-1.21\ios\SampleApp